# Select all li with a particular <span> and get link info within

Tags: jquery, html, select, get, html-lists

I want choose all the `<li>` in my html that have the `<span>Google Map</span>` in it and apply.

And get the value in href  with jQuery. I tried going through jQuery docs but could not figure it out. Is this possible?

```
<li><span>Google Maps Staic Link:</span> 
<a target="_blank" href="**Value To Get**" rel="nofollow">Map</a></li>
```

The actual HTML will be something like this.

```
<li><span>Name</span>Newyork:</li>
<li><span>Added:</span>23rd April</li>
<li><span>Google Map Link:</span> 
<a target="_blank" href="**Value To Get**" rel="nofollow">Map</a>
</li>
```

From this I only want the one with Google Map Link. The link will change but the span `<span>Google Map Link:</span>` will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('span:contains("Google Map")').next('a').attr('href');
```

that will give you an jQuery array object of all the hrefs

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks a million.

Comment: This would only get the first occurence, not an array.

Comment: in my case... there is no array. So ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   var href = $('li:has(span:contains(Google Map))').find('a').attr('href');
});​
```

You would need to invoke `.each()` if you expect more than one occurence.

Anyway, selectors like this look so wierd and odd, I'd suggest to use `.filter()` anyway.

Comment: +1! First one worked for me, but when as u said more than one occurrence is there this is the best solution. Maybe handy for future use.

Answer (score 0):

```
​$('span:contains("Google Map")').each(function(index){
    alert($(this).siblings(0).attr('href')); //Do whatever with href attr...
});​​​​​​​​​
```